# Putting Links in Parenthesis with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup's get_text() function only records the textual information of an HTML webpage. However, I want my program to return the href link of an  tag in parenthesis directly after it returns the actual text.

In other words, using get_text() will just return "17.602" on the following HTML:

```
<a class="xref fm:ParaNumOnly" href="17.602.html#FAR_17_602">17.602</a>
```

However, I want my program to return "17.602 (17.602.html#FAR_17_602)". How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: What if you need to print text from other tags, such as:

```
<p> Sample text.
<a class="xref fm:ParaNumOnly" href="17.602.html#FAR_17_602">17.602</a>
Sample closing text.
</p>
```

In other words, how would you compose a program that would print

```
Sample text. 17.602 (17.602.html#FAR_17_602) Sample closing text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the output using f-strings.

Access the tag's text using `.text`, and then access the `href` attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<a class="xref fm:ParaNumOnly" href="17.602.html#FAR_17_602">17.602</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

a_tag = soup.find("a")
print(f"{a_tag.text} ({a_tag['href']})")
```

Output:

```
17.602 (17.602.html#FAR_17_602)
```

Edit: You can use [`.next_sibling` and `.previous_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)

```
print(f"{a_tag.previous_sibling.strip()} {a_tag.text} ({a_tag['href']}) {a_tag.next_sibling.strip()}")
```

Output:

```
Sample text. 17.602 (17.602.html#FAR_17_602) Sample closing text.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if the <a> tag is enclosed in <p> tags, and there is text on either side of the <a> tag? How would you print all the other text as well as 17.602 (17.602.html#FAR_17_602)?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the example HTML

Comment: Okay, just did so.